# Understanding swiftstack storage

Tags: storage, cloud, openstack

I just wanted to make sure I understand swift FS properly. Is it possible to run a live VM operating system image on Swift like you can on a mounted SAN/NAS/Local storage? Or is it just for operations like a remote file server if you would, such as google Drive/DropBox and so on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is a object storage solution with REST based API. It is deployed at Wikipedia, Rackspace, HPcloud

You can use external solution if you are looking forward to use Swift as filesystem.

http://caimito.ngasi.com/

https://code.google.com/p/s3ql/

You can also check http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/associated_projects.html for list of all the associated project.

Hope it helps.